# Why does serialization work without implementing Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

Is it mandatory to implement Serializable class when serializing a class .I tried to put object data into file with and without serializable implementation and found absolutely no difference.

### snippet -1

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class SerializableTest {

    int a= 10;
    String test="Serialize test";

    public static void main(String [] args){

        SerializableTest test =new SerializableTest();
        test.save();
    }

    public void save(){

        try{

            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("save.res");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(test);
            os.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex ){
            System.out.println("Error in opening or saving file");

        }
        System.out.println("Complete");
    }
}
```

---

### snippet -2

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class SerializableTest **implements Serializable**{

    int a= 10;
    String test="Serialize test";

    public static void main(String [] args){

        SerializableTest test =new SerializableTest();
        test.save();
    }

    public void save(){

        try{

            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("save.res");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(test);
            os.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex ){
            System.out.println("Error in opening or saving file");

        }
        System.out.println("Complete");
    }
}
```

In both cases program ran fine and contents of save.res looked absolutely similar.

1. What is the advantage of implementing Serializable when I can do things without implementing.

Comment: 1) Try to serialize some custom class 2) Try to de-serialize from output to construct Object representation, you will get the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Serializable` should ideally be implemented by the object that needs to be serialized. `String` implements `Serializable`. You are serializing a `String` object. You are not serializing `SerializableTest`.

In other words, it does not matter if `SerializableTest` implements `Serializable` or not since `SerializableTest` is not the object that is being serialized.

Comment: Thanks everyone for reply, I got the concept now :)

Comment: Not sure why but at os.writeObject(test); test is an object  why would we term it as String ?